# can we use android tablet as an extended monitor

Tags: android, display, multiple-monitors

Is is possible to use an android tablet as an extended monitor to my laptop

Comment: Should be ón superusers

Comment: See also: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/1922/is-it-possible-to-use-an-android-device-as-a-second-monitor

Answer (score 3):

[Yes.](http://www.wired.com/gadgetlab/2011/03/use-your-android-tablet-as-a-second-computer-display/)

From the linked article:

> IDisplay, the not-so-well loved iOS app to turn a tablet or phone into a secondary display, has come to Android. Now, with this app and an Android tablet or phone (v2.1 or better), you can extend your display.

Comment: Nice find - but a bare link doesn't offer much help to the reader trying to decide whether to follow it. Your post adds a lot more to the site with a little bit of context included.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, use a VNC viewer like [this one](https://market.android.com/details?id=android.androidVNC) on your tablet, install a VNC server on your laptop and off you go ;-)

Comment: Can this arrangement _extend_ the desktop?